# Setting up LAMP Stack in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I am trying to setup LAMP stack on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS by installing each of the packages seperately in terminal and not by using LAMP software bundle packages. The following are the commands that I executed:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Is there any other configuration that needs to be done like configuring the apache2 server, phpmyadmin, etc...  I looked it up on google and unable to find recent results.

Appreicate your help

Edit: Updated the query with more information

Comment: Have you started Apache?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: apologies, the error I got above for a localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in the apache2 config file by typing:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then, type the following and save the file:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Now, restart the apache2 server by typing:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```